# Redis in Docker container with custom redis.conf file not attaching

Tags: ubuntu, docker, redis, docker-compose

I'm having trouble getting redis to start in a docker container. when I run

```
docker-compose up
```

I see the output

```
Starting redis_redis_1
Attaching to redis_redis_1
redis_redis_1 exited with code 0
```

after which, I can run

```
docker ps -a
```

to see
    [image: docker ps -a output]

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
redis:
    image: redis
    command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - /mnt/xvdb/redis/:/usr/local/etc/redis/
      - ./redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

This is the verbose output I get:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-172:~/redis$ docker-compose --verbose up --build
compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.yml
docker.auth.auth.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['/home/ubuntu/.docker/config.json', '/home/ubuntu/.dockercfg']
docker.auth.auth.find_config_file: No config file found
compose.cli.command.get_client: docker-compose version 1.9.0, build 2585387
docker-py version: 1.10.6
CPython version: 2.7.6
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker base_url: http+docker://localunixsocket
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker version: KernelVersion=3.13.0-48-generic, Os=linux, BuildTime=2016-12-12T23:50:16.747144109+00:00, ApiVersion=1.24, Version=1.12.4, GitCommit=1564f02, Arch=amd64, GoVersion=go1.6.4
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker info <- ()
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker info -> {u'Architecture': u'x86_64',
 u'BridgeNfIp6tables': True,
 u'BridgeNfIptables': True,
 u'CPUSet': True,
 u'CPUShares': True,
 u'CgroupDriver': u'cgroupfs',
 u'ClusterAdvertise': u'',
 u'ClusterStore': u'',
 u'Containers': 1,
 u'ContainersPaused': 0,
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=False, filters={u'label': [u'com.docker.compose.project=redis', u'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={u'label': [u'com.docker.compose.project=redis', u'com.docker.compose.service=redis', u'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 1 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- (u'e8617d77bbdcdd36be35a130ea7afd764a8777d0b2d4df0700a5bf708ed63810')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {u'AppArmorProfile': u'',
 u'Args': [u'redis-server', u'/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf'],
 u'Config': {u'AttachStderr': False,
             u'AttachStdin': False,
             u'AttachStdout': False,
             u'Cmd': [u'redis-server', u'/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf'],
             u'Domainname': u'',
             u'Entrypoint': [u'docker-entrypoint.sh'],
             u'Env': [u'affinity:container==3379fa24f2ec222251f97b39f194b629841b79e85707d62ee9a922becdb0cc40',
                      u'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image <- ('redis')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image -> {u'Architecture': u'amd64',
 u'Author': u'',
 u'Comment': u'',
 u'Config': {u'ArgsEscaped': True,
             u'AttachStderr': False,
             u'AttachStdin': False,
             u'AttachStdout': False,
             u'Cmd': [u'redis-server'],
             u'Domainname': u'',
             u'Entrypoint': [u'docker-entrypoint.sh'],
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={u'label': [u'com.docker.compose.project=redis', u'com.docker.compose.service=redis', u'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 1 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image <- ('redis')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image -> {u'Architecture': u'amd64',
 u'Author': u'',
 u'Comment': u'',
 u'Config': {u'ArgsEscaped': True,
             u'AttachStderr': False,
             u'AttachStdin': False,
             u'AttachStdout': False,
             u'Cmd': [u'redis-server'],
             u'Domainname': u'',
             u'Entrypoint': [u'docker-entrypoint.sh'],
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- (u'e8617d77bbdcdd36be35a130ea7afd764a8777d0b2d4df0700a5bf708ed63810')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {u'AppArmorProfile': u'',
 u'Args': [u'redis-server', u'/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf'],
 u'Config': {u'AttachStderr': False,
             u'AttachStdin': False,
             u'AttachStdout': False,
             u'Cmd': [u'redis-server', u'/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf'],
             u'Domainname': u'',
             u'Entrypoint': [u'docker-entrypoint.sh'],
             u'Env': [u'affinity:container==3379fa24f2ec222251f97b39f194b629841b79e85707d62ee9a922becdb0cc40',
                      u'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
...
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set([<Service: redis>])
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Starting producer thread for <Service: redis>
compose.service.start_container_if_stopped: Starting redis_redis_1
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker attach <- (u'e8617d77bbdcdd36be35a130ea7afd764a8777d0b2d4df0700a5bf708ed63810', stderr=True, stream=True, stdout=True)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker attach -> <generator object frames_iter at 0x7fd372c02c80>
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker start <- (u'e8617d77bbdcdd36be35a130ea7afd764a8777d0b2d4df0700a5bf708ed63810')
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set([])
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker start -> None
compose.parallel.parallel_execute_iter: Finished processing: <Service: redis>
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set([])
Attaching to redis_redis_1
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events <- (decode=True, filters={u'label': [u'com.docker.compose.project=redis', u'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events -> <generator object _stream_helper at 0x7fd372c02e60>
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait <- (u'e8617d77bbdcdd36be35a130ea7afd764a8777d0b2d4df0700a5bf708ed63810')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- (u'e8617d77bbdcdd36be35a130ea7afd764a8777d0b2d4df0700a5bf708ed63810')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait -> 0
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {u'AppArmorProfile': u'',
 u'Args': [u'redis-server', u'/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf'],
 u'Config': {u'AttachStderr': False,
             u'AttachStdin': False,
             u'AttachStdout': False,
             u'Cmd': [u'redis-server', u'/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf'],
             u'Domainname': u'',
             u'Entrypoint': [u'docker-entrypoint.sh'],
             u'Env': [u'affinity:container==3379fa24f2ec222251f97b39f194b629841b79e85707d62ee9a922becdb0cc40',
                      u'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
...
redis_redis_1 exited with code 0
```

docker logs gives me nothing

```
docker logs redis_redis_1
```

gives me nothing

[image: docker logs output]

Any help appreciated

Comment: What do you get when you make `docker logs redis_redis_1`?

Comment: @PascalLeMerrer Nothing... have updated the question (See last few lines)

Comment: @smur89 have you restarted the docker service? I hate to say it but I've had these sorts of errors and restarting docker has often fixed them.  Not confidence inspiring but if it works...

Comment: Just to rule it out as a source of issue, try removing the second mount ('./redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf') and placing your redis.conf directly into /mnt/xvdb/redis/.

Comment: Tried both of these suggestions, but get the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was able to get Redis to run with what I thought was the default config file. Because of the warning printed on the first line here.

````
redis_1  | 1:C 19 Dec 12:30:29.397 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis_1  |                 _._                                                  
redis_1  |            _.-``__ ''-._                                             
redis_1  |       _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 3.2.6 (00000000/0) 64 bit
redis_1  |   .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._                                   
redis_1  |  (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
redis_1  |  |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
redis_1  |  |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 1
redis_1  |   `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'                                   
redis_1  |  |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
redis_1  |  |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io        
redis_1  |   `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
redis_1  |  |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
redis_1  |  |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |                                  
redis_1  |   `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
redis_1  |       `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'                                       
redis_1  |           `-._        _.-'                                           
redis_1  |               `-.__.-'                                               
redis_1  | 
redis_1  | 1:M 19 Dec 12:30:29.399 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
redis_1  | 1:M 19 Dec 12:30:29.399 # Server started, Redis version 3.2.6
redis_1  | 1:M 19 Dec 12:30:29.400 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
redis_1  | 1:M 19 Dec 12:30:29.400 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
redis_1  | 1:M 19 Dec 12:30:29.400 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
redis_1  | 1:M 19 Dec 12:30:29.400 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
````

This is what led me to the redis.conf file in my original question, where I had overridden the default command.

After which I was able to check what was actually in the default config file.

```
docker exec db00a03fd187 cat /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

To find my custom config file was there being used.

So because I'm mapping my config file to the default directory, I guess I get that output. So, there was no issue.

Here's my docker-compose.yml file that I ended up with:

```
redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      - /mnt/xvdb/redis:/usr/local/etc/redis
```